# How to edit data in Primefaces DataTable without in-cell editing?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have 2 pages.

1. Add Page for add a new item [image: Add Page]
2. List Page for show all items [image: List Page]

When I click on Edit icon on List Page, I want to show selected data on Add Page for editing and update its data if I click on save button. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the row identifier as a parameter to the button. For example, assuming that `#{item}` is the currently iterated item and has some `Long id` property which uniquely identifies the item.

```
<p:button icon="ui-icon-pencil" outcome="edit.xhtml">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}" />
</p:button>
```

In the target page, `edit.xhtml`, you can use `<f:viewParam>` to convert, validate and set it as a bean property.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.item}" required="true" converter="itemConverter" />
</f:metadata>

...

<p:inputText value="#{bean.item.name}" />
<p:inputText value="#{bean.item.shortName}" />
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: BalusC, please suggest me.
I should handle add and update event in one page (Add Page) or separate into 2 page add event in Add Page and update event in Edit Page